# How to replace code to use RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which checks for "enter" key as well as prevent the use of `>` and `<` sign in the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function checkKeycode(e) {
  var keycode;
  if (window.event) // IE
    keycode = e.keyCode;
  else if (e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    keycode = e.which;
  if (keycode == 13) {

      //Get the button the user wants to have clicked
      var btn = document.getElementById(btnSearch);

      if (btn != null) { //If we find the button click it
          btn.click();
          event.keyCode = 0
      }

      //Removed when above code was added 12-09-13
      //CallSearch();

  }
}
 function CallSearch()  {
     var objsearchText = window.document.getElementById('txtSearchText');
     var searchText;
     if ((objsearchText!=null))
     {
         searchText = objsearchText.value;
         searchText = searchText.replace(/>/gi, " >");
         searchText = searchText.replace(/</gi, "< ");
         objsearchText.value = searchText;
     }    
     //This cookie is used for the backbutton to work in search on postback
     //This cookie must be cleared to prevent old search results from displayed    
     document.cookie='postbackcookie=';

     document.location.href="search_results.aspx?searchtext=";
 }  

</script>
```

How can I shorten the code to be more effecient and use the `onBlur` function and to use `RegExp` instead of replace? Or is replace a faster method than `RegExp`?

Comment: You are using regular expressions in replace. `/>/` is a regex.

Comment: What do you want to use the `onBlur` function for? Also, the [i modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) you're using in your regex is unnecessary since you are not trying to match letters.

Comment: Can't I combine both into one line? I want to use the `onBlur()` so when the user leaves the text box and replace the Lt and gt sign to ''

Comment: Make sure this is not your only validation. What happens when the user pastes a value that contains the forbidden characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that you want to prevent `<` and `>` chars. Here is an easier way, just ignore these chars when the keydown event occurs on them.

Also I suggest to use jQuery - if you can.

http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

```
var ignoredChars = [188, 190]; // <, >
$('#myTextField').keydown(function(e) {
   if(ignoredChars.indexOf(e.which) > -1) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     return false;
   }

})
.keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which === 13) {
     $('#searchButton').click();
  }
});
```

Just add this event handler to your textbox and **remove the regexp** replacements.
If you don't want characters to be input by user, surpress them as early as possible. This way you won't get in trouble fiddling them out of a big string later.

Comment: Works great. How do I replace the entire thing to JQuery? You are right, I should go with JQuery :)

Comment: updated answer so that pressing enter will trigger the search button. Don't forget to wrap with `$(document).ready(function(){...})`before selecting any DOM elements. good luck